# Scala - how to get the 'type' for a field using reflection api

Tags: scala, reflection

I am using Scala 2.11.0-M5.

I need to find the fields (members that are vars or vals) of a Scala class/type and for each field I need to find the class/type.

So far I have been able to get the field members but I can't figure out how to get the member's type once I have the member.

```
scala> class Account {
  var name: String = null;
  var accountNumber: String = null;
}     |      |      | 
defined class Account

scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> for (m <- typeOf[Account].members.filter(m => !m.isMethod)) {
 |   println(m)
 |   // ??? how do I get the member's type ????
 | }
variable accountNumber
variable name
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`typeSignature`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Symbols$Symbol):

```
scala> typeOf[Account].members.filter(!_.isMethod).foreach(
 |   sym => println(sym + " is a " + sym.typeSignature)
 | )
variable accountNumber is a String
variable name is a String
```

In this context this method will return a [`reflect.runtime.universe.Type`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Types$Type).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Just needed to use  m.typeSignature

```
for (m <- typeOf[Account].members.filter(m => !m.isMethod)) {
     | println(m)
     | println(m.typeSignature)
     | }
variable accountNumber
String
variable name
String
```